# Log4X for flow control

Tags: java, php, c++, workflow, log4j

I m in a project which my co-workers want to use log4cpp, log4php or log4j for flow control, ie: they want to log things, parse it and then flow control based on that information.

I told them that log4X should only be used to log, report errors and run time information.

How can I convince them not to use log4cpp or log4php or any log4x for flow control?

or do you think there is nothing wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a classic case of using the wrong tool for the job. There are many ways to do flow control and even whole servers for that purpose. Mule, IBM Message Broker to name a couple. As you say, LogX is for logging. The concept of trying to base the flow of messages, execution or whatever on the parsed output of a logger is so far wrong I cannot even begin to figure out why anyone would suggest such as bad idea, never mind adopt it. And there are so many ways to screw it up too. Never mind the fact of how do they intend to do real logging if their logging framework is not being used for it.

It never ceases to amaze me how often people in IT manage to make such decisions.